# how to combine values of columns in the tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-management

I have two variables, 'landcover' (categorical: 1-5) and 'field' (categorical: 1-2). Where there's a value for 'field', there should be an `na` in the 'landcover' column and vice versa. How would I go about combining these into a single variable in the `tidyverse`?

Example code looks something like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(landcover = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, NA, 4, 5, 1, NA, 3, NA, 5),
fieldsampled = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 2, NA))
```

I expect to start out, I'd need to change 'field' values to something different like 6 and 7:

```
dat %>% mutate(field = recode(field, 1 = 6, 2 = 7))
```

But unaware of a handy `dplyr` function to then combine the two columns into one. Suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The dplyr::coalesce function (like the SQL equivalent) is useful here for combining two vectors to get the first non-NA. We can also add 5 to the fieldsampled one to create a number that doesn't overlap with the landcover values.

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(field = coalesce(landcover, fieldsampled + 5))
```

Result

```
   landcover fieldsampled field
1          1           NA     1
2          2           NA     2
3          3           NA     3
4          4           NA     4
5          5           NA     5
6          1           NA     1
7          2           NA     2
8          3           NA     3
9          4           NA     4
10         5           NA     5
11         1           NA     1
12         2           NA     2
13        NA            2     7
14         4           NA     4
15         5           NA     5
16         1           NA     1
17        NA            1     6
18         3           NA     3
19        NA            2     7
20         5           NA     5
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I was unaware of coalesce. Super simple and helpful answer!